# Eclipse Tomcat - replaces Conf files

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, context.xml, server.xml

I made some changes in the context.xml and server.xml files of Tomcat server. I then run the tomcat in debug mode from within eclipse. THis replaces all the changes I Made in the configuration files. I had to redo those changes, and restart the server - it is fine then. I dont know why the conf files are replaced. When I check the file modification time, it is when I started the server in debug mode. WHat could be causign this? Any help is appreciated please.

The conf files shouldnt be replaced when I start the server. It is as if, new default conf files are created during the server startup and is written to the conf folder.

Comment: Where did you make changes to those files? The instance that you're running has them in the Servers project since you can have *multiple* configurations with their own set of web apps for a *single* installed runtime and location.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.